# Jackson is unable to deserialize jsonstring to Textract object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, jackson

Unable to deserialize Textract model object like DocumentMetadata - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/textract/model/DocumentMetadata.html - from AWS Java SDK v2. Getting following error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `software.amazon.awssdk.services.textract.model.DocumentMetadata` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 57] (through reference chain: com.amazon.fdmextractionserviceextractfromdocument.data.internal.AnalyseExpenseResponse["DocumentMetadata"]): com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `software.amazon.awssdk.services.textract.model.DocumentMetadata` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 57] (through reference chain: com.amazon.fdmextractionserviceextractfromdocument.data.internal.AnalyseExpenseResponse["DocumentMetadata"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1764)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1209)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1415)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:363)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:196)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:325)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:188)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3548)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3516)
    at com.amazon.fdmextractionserviceextractfromdocument.data.TextractOutputBuilder.getTextractOutput(TextractOutputBuilder.kt:22)
    at com.amazon.fdmextractionserviceextractfromdocument.domainlogic.ExtractDataComponent.extractData(ExtractDataComponent.kt:12)
    at com.amazon.fdmextractionserviceextractfromdocument.service.ExtractDataActivity.extractData(ExtractDataActivity.kt:14)
    at com.amazon.fdmextractionserviceextractfromdocument.LambdaMain.handleRequest(LambdaMain.kt:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

*Most of the online resources refer to using annotations for Jackson. In this case that is not valid as the models are imported from AWS service. Also tried using Gson. Worst case scenario solution, create models locally.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking the implementation of the model class for DocumentMetadata, the default constructor and property getters and setters are part of its Builder interface implementation. The class of this implementation can be obtained by using the static method `.serializableBuilderClass()` on DocumentMetadata (in this case).

Using Jackson annotation `@JsonDeserialize` on the data class property, jackson can be instructed to use the above class for to construct DocumentMetadata (instead of the POJO itself). Following code sample for Kotlin data class worked for me:

```
data class AnalyseExpenseResponse(
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DocumentMetadataDeserializer::class)
    var documentMetadata: DocumentMetadata? = null
) {

    class DocumentMetadataDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<DocumentMetadata>() {

        override fun deserialize(
            jsonParser: JsonParser,
            deserializationContext: DeserializationContext
        ): DocumentMetadata {
            return jsonParser.readValueAs(DocumentMetadata.serializableBuilderClass()).build()
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using Textract models from AWS Java SDK v1 work out-of-the-box without requiring any additional workarounds like above, and thus keeping the code clean. This also helped with nested models without requiring to re-create the data classes in the code. The entire AnalyzeExpenseResult for example, can be obtained with simply:

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, AnalyzeExpenseResult::class.java)
```

(Am new to Java and Kotlin, but this is what I could figure out, please let me know if there are more elegant ways to make Jackson work for the v2 version of the SDK)